# Find the limit of function using Taylor series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, functions, taylor-expansion

Good evening,

I'm somehow stuck on solving some easy exercises :

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} x^{3/2}\bigl(\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x-1}-2\,\sqrt{x}\bigr)$$

Comment: I have LaTeXified your question. Please check it is correct.

Comment: Yes, it is. I'm sorry, I don't know how to use equation formatting on this website, yet.

Comment: Clement, I've tried to use Taylor's series for square root (for example, sqrt(x-1) rewriting as sqrt(1+(x-2)) and so on. In this case, a lot of simplification happens. Then, I tried to rewrite x=1/h and then again do similar things, but still, somehow i end up with infinity...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\sqrt{1+x}=\sqrt{x}\,\Bigl(1+\frac1x\Bigr)^{1/2}=\sqrt{x}\,\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{1/2}{n}x^n=\sqrt{x}\,\Bigl(1+\frac12\,\frac1x+\dots\Bigr).
$$
Similarly for $\sqrt{x-1}$.

Comment: Can you correct me?
Since for the x-1 we have opposite sign (if we take x at the beginning) , then Taylor series will be also different with signs after 1 from the first sqrt(1+x), so then if we add them then only x^(3/2)[ sqrt(x)+sqrt(x)-2sqrt(x)]. And I get 0 * infinity. Where I'm so horribly wrong? Thank you for Your time.

Comment: Those terms effectively cancel, but you have to compute the next term in the Taylor series (the $\dots$) involving $1/x^2$.

Answer (score 0):

it is the following term $$-1/4-{\frac {5}{64\,{x}^{2}}}-{\frac {21}{512\,{x}^{4}}}+O \left( {x}^
{-5} \right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+1}},\qquad \sqrt{x-1}-\sqrt{x}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x-1}},$$
hence:
$$\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x-1}-2\sqrt{x}=\frac{\sqrt{x-1}-\sqrt{x+1}}{(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+1})(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x-1})}=\frac{-2}{(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+1})(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x-1})(\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{x+1})}\approx\frac{-2}{(2\sqrt{x})^3}$$
and the limit is $\color{red}{-\frac{1}{4}}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}&x\sqrt x\left(\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x-1}-2\sqrt x\right)=x\left(\sqrt{x^2+x}+\sqrt{x^2-x}-2x\right)=\\{}\\
&=x\frac{-2x^2+2\sqrt{x^4-x^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+x}+\sqrt{x^2-x}+2x}=\frac{-2x^2+2\sqrt{x^4-x^2}}{\sqrt{1+\frac1x}+\sqrt{1-\frac1x}+2}=\\{}\\
&=\frac{4(x^4-x^2)-4x^4}{\left(\sqrt{1+\frac1x}+\sqrt{1-\frac1x}+2\right)\left(2\sqrt{x^4-x^2}+2x^2\right)}\\{}\\
&=\frac{-4x^2}{2x^2\left(\sqrt{1+\frac1x}+\sqrt{1-\frac1x}+2\right)\left(\sqrt{1-\frac1{x^2}}+1\right)}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}\frac{-2}{(1+1+2)(1+1)}=-\frac14\end{align}$$